# Evaluating an If expression inside Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I was trying to display some value inside a `InputField`. Usually it looks like this:

```
DynamicModule[{a=1,b=20,fuc="1"},
 Deploy[Style[Panel[
 Grid[Transpose[{
   {"Input Format","Value"},
   {PopupMenu[Dynamic[fuc],{"1","2"}],
    InputField[Dynamic[a],Number,Enabled->Dynamic[fuc=="1"]]}
  }], Alignment->Right], ImageMargins->10]]]]
```

However I wanted to change what is displayed in `InputField` according to what `fuc` is. I was trying to put `If[]` inside `Dynamic`. But it failed:

```
DynamicModule[{a=1,b=20,fuc="1"},
 Deploy[Style[Panel[
  Grid[Transpose[{
   {"Input Format","Value"},
   {PopupMenu[Dynamic[fuc],{"1","2"}], 
    InputField[Dynamic[If[fuc=="1",a,b]],Number,Enabled->Dynamic[fuc=="1"]]}
   }], Alignment->Right], ImageMargins->10]]]]
```

I can not change the value of a in the InputField even if fuc is chosen to be "1". The error message says:

> ```
> Set::write: "Tag If in If[True,FE`a$$570,FE`b$$570] is Protected."
> ```

Any idea how to solve this problem? I do need some `if` logic in `InputField`!
Thanks

Comment: I see i have to move If out side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update. Thanks to Eldo, Dynamic is needed outside the InputField.

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 20, fuc = "1"},
 Deploy[Style[Panel[Grid[Transpose[
      {
       {"Input Format", "Value"},
       {PopupMenu[Dynamic[fuc], {"1", "2"}],
        Dynamic@InputField[
         If[fuc == "1", a, b],
         Number,
         Enabled -> Dynamic[fuc == "1"]
         ]
        }
       }
      ],
     Alignment -> Right]
    , ImageMargins -> 10
    ]
   ]
  ]]
```

Comment: I think InputField should display `20` when "2" is selected. If this is the case you have to write `Dynamic@InputField[...]`

Comment: @eldo, you are right. Will correct, thanks.

Comment: Nasser, do you understand why when a number is entered into the input field for `a`, it displays the new number, but `a` is not changed?  (At least for me, Mac OS, V9.0.1.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 The first argument of `InputField` can only be a settable lhs if it's inside of a `Dynamic` (and, of course, that `Dynamic` has a sensible setting function).  Otherwise, what the FE receives is literally the evaluated argument of the `InputField` which, in this case, would be `InputField[1, Number, Enabled->Dynamic[fuc == "1"]]`.  The `a` is long gone.

Comment: @JohnFultz  Thanks. Of course. Sort of a "D'oh" moment for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways.  One of them may be what the OP alluded to in a comment; in any case, I'll give a complete solution below.

First, using `If` inside one `InputField`:  The trick here is to use the second argument of `Dynamic`.

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 20, fuc = "1"}, 
 Deploy[Style[
   Panel[Grid[
     Transpose[{{"Input Format", "Value"},
       {PopupMenu[Dynamic[fuc], {"1", "2"}], 
        InputField[
         Dynamic[If[fuc == "1", a, b], 
                 If[fuc == "1", a = #, b = #] &],
         Number, Enabled -> Dynamic[fuc == "1"]]}}],
     Alignment -> Right], 
    ImageMargins -> 10]]]]
```

Second, using `If` to switch between two `InputFields`:  The trick here is to wrap `If` in `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 20, fuc = "1"}, 
 Deploy[Style[
   Panel[Grid[
     Transpose[{{"Input Format", "Value"},
       {PopupMenu[Dynamic[fuc], {"1", "2"}],
        Dynamic@If[fuc == "1",
          InputField[Dynamic[a], Number, Enabled -> True],
          InputField[Dynamic[b], Number, Enabled -> False]]}}], 
     Alignment -> Right], ImageMargins -> 10]]]]
```

In both cases one can change the value of `a` and not of `b`.